# DotNetNuke saving credentials error, Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: windows-server-2008, dotnetnuke, vps

I have installed dnn on windows server 2008 (not R2).

Everything seem to be working ok with my DNN install but when I came to enter my store credentials I received the following error

`Critical Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Going into Admin > Event viewer I see a few entries with the following

```
ActiveTabID:36
ActiveTabName:Extensions
RawURL:/Host/Extensions/ctl/Store/mid/345/portalid/0?popUp=true
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx
AbsoluteURLReferrer:http://109.123.110.124/Host/Extensions/ctl/Store/mid/345/portalid/0?popUp=true
UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:ca46a6b6-bc7d-4b24-b6f8-e30cb0768d73
InnerException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Extensions.Store.OnSaveClick
StackTrace:
Message:
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Extensions.Store.OnSaveClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I assume you're using the correct DNN Store credentials? As in you can successfully log in to the store with the same credentials?

Comment: @ChrisHammond yes I am sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem while installing the forums module. I was not able to get an answer on how to fix it. I ended up installing an older version of it and it worked fine. 
Also, Make sure that all the permissions for files and folders for the site are set to read and write.. I had a few problems with files and folders that were not set to read and write and it kept on throwing error messages.... If you get really stuck I would recommended using the forum listed below.
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums